# How to get this neumorphic styled input using CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

How to get this neumorphic styled input using CSS?

[image: Expected style]

This is my code it's not sharp enough as in the image attached. Other than changing tweaking the box shadow is there anything else that can be added to this?

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
body {
  background: #efefef;
}

input {
  padding: 1.5em 5em;
  background: #efefef;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset -6px -6px 14px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7), inset -6px -6px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 6px 6px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, .075), inset 6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.form-input {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.form-input .icon {
  left: 0;
  margin: .5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-input">
  <label for="input4" class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></label>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Text' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

:root {
  --primary-light: #8abdff;
  --primary: #6d5dfc;
  --primary-dark: #5b0eeb;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --greyLight-1: #e4ebf5;
  --greyLight-2: #c8d0e7;
  --greyLight-3: #bec8e4;
  --greyDark: #9baacf;
}

body {
  background: #efefef;
}

input {
  width: 20.4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding-left: 4rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.5rem var(--greyLight-3), inset -0.2rem -0.2rem 0.5rem var(--white);
  background: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: var(--greyDark);
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--greyLight-3);
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--greyLight-3);
}
input::placeholder {
  color: var(--greyLight-3);
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.6rem var(--greyLight-2), -0.2rem -0.2rem 0.5rem var(--white);
}
input:focus + .search__icon {
  color: var(--primary);
}

.form-input {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  
}

.form-input .icon {
  height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  color: var(--greyDark);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  top: 6px;
}
```

I used variables so you can make it according to your needs.